# Perform calculations on MySQL Load Data

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I have the following two sql statements

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '~/data/geo_blocks.csv' INTO TABLE geo_blocks FIELDS  ENCLOSED BY '\"'TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (ip_start, ip_end, location_id);
```

&

```
update geo_blocks set index_geo = (ip_end - mod(ip_end, 65536));
```

Is there a way combine the LOAD DATA statement to perform the calculation at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try SET clause in [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) command -

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '~/data/geo_blocks.csv'
INTO TABLE geo_blocks
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '\"'TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(@ip_start, @ip_end, location_id)
SET index_geo = @ip_end - MOD(@ip_end, 65536);
```

Comment: seems there is an extra ) at the end of the set.

Comment: The corrected statement will be

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '~/data/geo_blocks.csv' INTO TABLE geo_blocks FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '\"'TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (@ip_start, @ip_end, location_id) SET index_geo = @ip_end - MOD(@ip_end, 65536);`

Comment: I have removed extra ')'. Thanks.